# How to assign value to matrix element that satisfy a certain condition?

Tags: matrix, julia, diagonal

I need to create new matrix from matrix A. All elements in new matrix need to be elements from matrix A except elements on main diagonal. Odd elements on main diagonal need to be divided by 2, and even elements on main diagonal need to be multiplied by 3.

```
julia> A=rand(1:10 ,3,3)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  5  3  1
  5  2  6
 10  1  7
```

I decided to create new matrix from two matrixes. 
First, I decided to keep all elements from matrix A, except elements on main diagonal, in matrix B which has zeros on main diagonal:

```
julia> B=A .* .~ I(3)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  0  3  1
  5  0  6
 10  1  0
```

Then I wanted to create matrix C which has the same main diagonal as A, and all other elements are zeros:

```
julia> C=A .* one(A)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  5  0  0
  0  2  0
  0  0  7
```

Finally, my goal was to make all changes on matrix C and then create final matrix as

> `D = C + B;`

I have problem making changes on main diagonal, because I am not sure **how to assign value to matrix elements that satisfy a certain condition**.
For example, how to multiply even elements on main diagonal by 3, and divide odd elements on main diagonal by 2?

I tried using replace:  `replace!(x->x%2!=0 ? x/2 : x, C)` but it returns error.
I tried using `C[C .% 2 .!=0]` and than doing something with it, but I couldn't get it right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i notice a problem in your formulation. if you divide an odd number by two, the result is not an Int64, (7/2) = 3.5. is that right?

Comment: @longemen3000 Yes, you are right. I overlooked it... Do you know how I can solve that or maybe convert it?

Comment: you can change the generation of the matrix, from `rand(1:10,3,3)` to `rand(1.0:10.0,3,3)`. other problem is that the `iseven` method doesnt work with floating point numbers, but that can be replaced by the function `my_iseven(x) = rem(x,2) == zero(x)`

Comment: @longemen3000 The key was to change generation of the matrix to `A=rand(1.0:10.0 , 3,3)` and then `replace!(x->x%2!=0 ? x/2 : x, C)` worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about a simple loop?

```
function change_diagonal!(A)
    @inbounds for i = 1:size(A,1)
        if iseven(A[i,i])
            A[i,i] = 3*A[i,i]
        else
            A[i,i] = A[i,i]/2
        end
    end
    return A
end
```

One problem with this is that your matrix is of type Int64, and dividing an odd number by two doesn't produce an integer. but, in general, if you want to do an operation only on the main elements of a dense matrix, a simple loop is easy and fast. it's important to note that this modifies the matrix in-place, so there isn't any memory allocations when executing the operation.if we extend this to be more general:

```
function change_diagonal!(f,A)
    @inbounds for i = 1:size(A,1)
        A[i,i] = f(A[i,i]) 
    end
    return A
end
```

You can pass any function and that function will be mapped on the diagonal elements of your matrix.

EDIT: there is other way, I don't know if is faster (probably don't) but for the sake of completeness, here its the idea: you can generate a vector that corresponds to a view of the diagonal of the matrix, so when you modify that vector, then you modify the original matrix. here is a function that generates that view:

```
function diagonal_view(A)
    return @view A[diagind(A)]
end
```

now, you can work with the diagonal as if was a simple vector:

```
A = rand(1.0:10.0,5,5)
diagA = diagonal_view(A)
diagA .= 40.0 #all elements of the diagonal of A are changed to 40.0
map!(x->2x,diagA,diagA) # another way to modify the diagonal, doubles the values
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! I will try both ways. Best regards!

Comment: @VasilijeBursac In Julia loops are your friends. You should get used to using them. They are almost always the fastest solution, and in some/many cases they are both more elegant, easier to write, and easier to read. 'Vectorized' implementations should be used when they are easy and convenient to write, not in cases like you have here, where the vectorized code is hard to write and difficult to understand.

Comment: @DNF I will definitely get used to using loops. I started learning Julia two days ago so I'm still getting used to it. Thank you very much for the explanation and advice! Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Problem with this is that matrix A was of type Int64, and dividing an odd number by two doesn't produce an integer. If you divide an odd number by two, the result is not an Int64, (7/2) = 3.5 .
The key was to change generation of the matrix to `A=rand(1.0:10.0 , 3,3)` and then `replace!(x->x%2!=0 ? x/2 : x, C)` and `replace!(x->x%2==0 ? x*3 : x, C)`  worked perfectly!

Big thanks to @longemen3000 for pointing this out!